# $c_0(2^{\kappa})$ does not embed in $\ell_\infty(\kappa)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

How to prove that $(c_0(2^\kappa),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ does not embed into $(\ell_\infty(\kappa),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$? Recall that $(c_0(2^\kappa),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is the Banach space of all families $(a_\lambda)_{\lambda<2^k}$ such that
$\{\lambda<2^\kappa\,\colon\,|a_\lambda|\geq\varepsilon\}$ is finite for all $\varepsilon>0$.

Answer (score 3):

The space $\ell_\infty(\mathcal k)$ is a dual space, and a result by Rosenthal implies that if $X^*$ contains $c_0(\Gamma)$ then it contains $\ell_\infty(\Gamma)$, and the density character of $\ell_\infty(\Gamma)$ is strictly bigger than that of $c_0(\Gamma)$.

See Corollary 1.5 in [the paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm37/sm3712.pdf) H.P. Rosenthal, On relatively disjoint families of measures, with some applications to Banach space theory. Studia Math. 37 (1970), 13-36. (Correction, ibid., 311-313.)

Comment: Every weakly compact subset of $l_{\infty}(\kappa)$ has topological weight at most $\kappa$. The reason is that if $W$ is weakly compact then $ (W, w)$ and $(W,w^*)$ are homeomorphic and the topological weight in the $w^*$ topology of the norm bounded subsets of $l_{\infty}(\kappa)$ is at most $\kappa$.This actually holds for every dual Banach space. Now notice that the basis of $c_0 ( \Gamma ) $ together with 0 is weakly compact with topological weight equal to the cardinality of $\Gamma$.